# Why does lein run hang?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have created a Leiningen project for Exercise 2 from [here](http://www.braveclojure.com/zombie-metaphysics/#Exercises). My code looks like this:

```
(ns random-quotes.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as str])
  (:gen-class))

(defn word-count [s]
  (frequencies (str/split (first (str/split s #"\n")) #"\s")))

(def quote-url "http://www.braveclojure.com/random-quote")

(def total-word-count (atom {}))

(defn update-word-count []
  (future
    (swap! total-word-count
           (partial merge-with +)
           (word-count (slurp quote-url)))))

(defn quote-word-count [n]
  (doseq [quote-future (doall (repeatedly n update-word-count))]
    @quote-future)
  @total-word-count)

(defn -main [n]
  (doseq [entry (sort-by val (quote-word-count (bigdec n)))]
    (println entry)))
```

All pretty straightforward. When I run, e.g., `(-main 5)` in `lein repl`, it runs, prints, and returns as expected. However, when I try `lein run 5` instead, it runs and prints but never exits, so I am forced to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get my terminal back.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure has a thread pool that it keeps running for use by the agents. Because those threads are still alive, the JVM can't tell that you're program is done. It's just **sitting there waiting for the agents to exit**. You can make them finish by calling `(shutdown-agents)` at the end of your program as described [here](http://clojure.org/agents). Futures use agents.

`clojure.core/future-call` calls an agent like this:

```
(let [f (binding-conveyor-fn f)
      fut (.submit clojure.lang.Agent/soloExecutor ^Callable f)]
```

which actually starts your code running. You would not be the only one to voice [some criticism](http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/06/08/clojure-agent-thread-pools/) of this, and we all hope a more elegant solution is found.

Comment: @Elogent - You invoked the agents when you used `future`.

Comment: thanks @Elogent I'll edit to include that in the answer.